# Missing artifact when deploy profile bunle on frabric 8

Tags: deployment, fabric8

I have a question about profile bundle deployment on fabric server.

If profile bundle was deployed on fabric and I want to deploy new version. I have to deploy two times, then artefacts, features won't missing.

[image]

Some features missing when I `fabric8:deploy` 1st time. 2nd time it won't missing.